# Jquery: slideToggle() multiple divs independently using one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Markup:

```
<div>
    <h3 class = "trigger">Heading 1</h3>
    <ul class = "toggle">
        <li>Line One</li>
        <li>Line Two</li>
        <li>Line Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <h3 class = "trigger">Heading 2</h3>
    <ul class = "toggle">
        <li>Line One</li>
        <li>Line Two</li>
        <li>Line Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the JQuery:

```
$(".toggle").slideUp();
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(".toggle").slideToggle("slow");
  });
```

I'd like to be able to toggle these `<ul>`s independently. Currently, when either `<h3>` title is clicked both divs toggle...

code is at: http://jsfiddle.net/CPvCZ/4/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is quite simple:

```
$(".toggle").slideUp();
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".toggle").slideToggle("slow");
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CkTRa/